# Why printf ("%d", ~a); displays -4 when a is equal to 3?

Tags: c, char, printf, unsigned, negation

Running the following program display -4 while 252 is expected:

```
unsigned char a=3;
printf ("%d", ~a);
```

Why this code doesn't display 252?

I also tested the folowings according to the proposed answer:

```
printf ("%u", ~a);
```

displays: 4294967292

```
printf ("%hu", ~a);
```

displays: 65532

Why `~a` doesn't return an `unsigned char` since a **is** an `unsigned char`?

My question is not what should I do to display 252 ? My question is Why 252 is not displayed?

Comment: You should print with `%u` format specifier, since your variable is an unsigned char!

Comment: THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE OF "How to print an unsigned char in C?" PLEASE READ THE QUESTION BEFORE MARKING AS DUPLICATE.

Comment: I agree that this is not exact duplicate, and should be reopened. However, please do not use CAPS in your posts as that is considered shouting, and impolite. Also please do not include commentary on your question text.

Comment: I understand, but I'm a bit I'm fed up of always fighting against guy that don't read the questions and mark them as duplicate. That's really really paintfull.

Comment: You have a mistake in the edits you made. [`"%hu"` gives you `65532`, while `"%hhu"` should give you the expected `252`](https://ideone.com/Ny3bte).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In addition to [the answer of @Someprogrammerdude](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53479487/3975177), here are the relevant passages from The Book<sup>1)</sup>:

#### [Unary arithmetic operators (§6.5.3.3/4)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#6.5.3.3p4)

> **The result of the *~* operator is the bitwise complement of its
>   (promoted** *[* ***!!*** *]* **) operand** (that is, each bit in the result is set if and only
>   if the corresponding bit in the converted operand is not set). **The
>   integer promotions are performed on the operand, and the result has
>   the promoted type.** If the promoted type is an unsigned type, the
>   expression *~E* is equivalent to the maximum value representable in that
>   type minus *E*.

#### [Arithmetic operands - Boolean, characters, and integers (§6.3.1.1)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#6.3.1.1):

> 1. Every integer type has an integer conversion rank defined as follows:
>
>    - No two signed integer types shall have the same rank, even if they have the same representation.
>    - The rank of a signed integer type shall be greater than the rank of any signed integer type with less precision.
>    - The rank of *long long int* shall be greater than the rank of *long int*, which shall be greater than the rank of *int*, which shall be greater than the rank of *short int*, which shall be greater than the rank of *signed char*.
>    - The rank of any *unsigned* integer type shall equal the rank of the corresponding signed integer type, if any.
>    - The rank of any standard integer type shall be greater than the rank of any extended integer type with the same width.
>    - The rank of *char* shall equal the rank of *signed char* and *unsigned char*.
>    - The rank of *_Bool* shall be less than the rank of all other standard integer types.
>    - The rank of any enumerated type shall equal the rank of the compatible integer type (see 6.7.2.2).
>    - The rank of any extended *signed* integer type relative to another extended *signed* integer type with the same precision is implementation-defined, but still subject to the other rules for determining the integer conversion rank.
>    - For all integer types *T1*, *T2*, and *T3*, if *T1* has greater rank than *T2* and *T2* has greater rank than *T3*, then *T1* has greater rank than *T3*.
> 2. The following may be used in an expression wherever an *int* or *unsigned int* may be used:
>
>    - An object or expression with an integer type whose integer conversion rank is less than or equal to the rank of *int* and *unsigned int*.
>    - A bit-field of type *_Bool*, *int*, *signed int*, or *unsigned int*. **If an *int* can represent all values of the original type, the value is converted to an *int*; otherwise, it is converted to an *unsigned int*. These are called the integer promotions.<sup>48)</sup>** All other types are unchanged by the integer promotions.
> 3. The integer promotions preserve value including sign. As discussed earlier, whether a "plain" *char* is treated as *signed* is implementation-defined.
>
> <sup>48) The integer promotions are applied only: as part of the usual arithmetic conversions, to certain argument expressions, to the operands of the unary *+*, *-*, and ***~* operators**, and to both operands of the shift operators, as specified by their respective subclauses.</sup>

### Your Question:

> Why `~a` doesn't return an `unsigned char` since `a` is an `unsigned char`?

Because integer promotions apply.

> ```
> unsigned char a = 3;
> printf ("%d", ~a);
> ```

`a` is an `unsigned char`, a type with a range that can be represented by an `int`. So `a` gets promoted to an `int`. Assuming 32-bit wide `int`s and [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement):

3<sub>10</sub> = `0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0011`<sub>2</sub>
~3<sub>10</sub> = `1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1100`<sub>2</sub>

The result interpreted as `signed int` is negative because the most significant bit, the sign bit, is set.

Convert to decimal:

    `1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1100`<sub>2</sub>
 ¬ `0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0011`<sub>2</sub>
 + `0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001`<sub>2</sub>
   ────────────────────────────
    `0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0100`<sub>2</sub>

0100<sub>2</sub> = 0 × 2<sup>3</sup> + 1 × 2<sup>2</sup> + 0 × 2<sup>2</sup> + 0 × 2<sup>2</sup>
           = *1* × 2<sup>2</sup>
           =   4<sub>10</sub>
           = −4<sub>10</sub> (with the original sign)

#### ~> `printf()` prints `-4`.

To get the desired result of 252 with your original code which uses `"%d"` as format specifier, some casting would be needed:

```
unsigned char a = 3;
printf("%d\n", (int)((unsigned char) ~a));  // prints 252
//              ^^^   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//               |          cast the result of ~a back to unsigned char *)
//               |          to discard the bits > CHAR_BIT
//               cast the char back to int to agree with the format specifier
```

<sup>*)Thanks to chux who made me remember that `char` could be `signed`! A cast to (possibly `signed`) `char` would give the wrong result of -4.</sup>

To get the same result without a cast, you could use the length modifier `hh`:

#### [The fprintf function (§7.19.6.1/7)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#7.19.6.1p7)

> The length modifiers and their meanings are:
>   *hh*  Specifies that a following *d*, *i*, *o*, *u*, *x*, or *X* conversion specifier applies to a *signed char* or *unsigned char* argument (the argument will have been promoted according to the integer promotions, but its value shall be converted to *signed char* or *unsigned char* before printing); or that a following *n* conversion specifier applies to a pointer to a signed char argument.
>   *[...]*

```
unsigned char a = 3;
printf("%hhu\n", ~a);  // prints 252
```

### The problem with your other attempts:

> ```
> printf ("%u", ~a);
> ```
>
> displays: 4294967292
>
> ```
> printf ("%hu", ~a);
> ```
>
> displays: 65532

Since `~a` is an `int`eger, it is not the correct type for the format specifier `u` and

#### [The fprintf function (§7.19.6.1/9)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#7.19.6.1p9):

> If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined.<sup>248)</sup> **If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.**

<sup>1) ISO/IEC 9899/Cor3:2007 aka C99:TR3 aka C99</sup>

Comment: Detail: `~a` as an `int`  with `"%u"` is UB when `~a` in not in the `unsigned` range - as it is in this case (-4). C11 §6.5.2.2 6

Comment: @chux It would be easier if you quoted the passage you are referring to.

Comment: `printf("%d\n", (int)((char) ~a));` print 252 when `char` is _unsigned_ and print -4 when `char` is _signed_.  Needs review.  Suggest `printf("%u\n", (unsigned char) ~a);`

Comment: The whole ref is too long for a comment: C11 §6.5.2.2 6 excerpts: "If the function is defined with a type that includes a prototype, and
either the prototype ends with an ellipsis (, ...) or the types of the arguments after
promotion are not compatible with the types of the parameters, the behavior is undefined.
. . . , except for the following cases:
— one promoted type is a signed integer type, the other promoted type is the
corresponding unsigned integer type, and the value is representable in both types;"

Comment: @chux, Yes, I read that before, but i am not certain what \*exactly\* you reffer to.

Comment: @chux *Suggest `printf("%u\n", (unsigned char) ~a);`* – agreed and changed.

Comment: "~a is an integer, it is not the correct type for the format specifier u" leading to UB is not sufficient.  "~a is an integer, it is not the correct type for the format specifier u" **and** `~a` not in `unsigned` range is  UB.

Comment: @chux disagree: [C11 6.5.2.2p7](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#): *If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that does include a prototype, the arguments are implicitly converted, as if by assignment, to the types of the corresponding parameters, taking the type of each parameter to be the unqualified version of its declared type. **The ellipsis notation in a function prototype declarator causes argument type conversion to stop after the last declared parameter. The default argument promotions are performed on trailing arguments**.*

Comment: It is not a _promotion_ issue but a "the value is representable in both types" one.  `printf("%u\n", 42);  printf("%d\n", 42u);` are not UB.  `printf("%u\n", -42);` is UB.

Comment: @chux the parameter passed is `int`. What is the other type?

Comment: @Swordfish: I think you want your 1) note to be "[ISO/IEC 9899:2018](https://webstore.iec.ch/publication/63478)" aka C18

Comment: @pmg Why would i want that?

Comment: Because you call it "The Book" :)

Comment: @pmg Well, The (old, rusty, nasty, still relevant) Book.

Comment: @chux Did you give up on me? :(

Comment: Deeper issue than for comment exchange.  Perhaps I'll post as  a question later.

Answer (score 4):

Because `~a` is an `int` not a character. If you want to print it as 8-bit unsigned integer type use the format `"%hhu"` as in

```
printf("%hhu\n", ~a);
```

The `hh` prefix is fo the 8-bit part, the `u` for unsiged.

It might also be helpful to learn about [integer promotions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Integer_promotions) as well as how [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) works for representing negative numbers.

From the link about integer promitions:

> integer promotions are applied ... to the operand of the unary bitwise operator `~`

Your problem is a mix of issues, discussed above.

Comment: Damn dude, nice answer, which makes now question the dupe I chose. What do you think? Should I remove it?

Comment: @gsamaras It's maybe not the perfect one, but could still be linked as related.

Comment: Are you sure that ~a is an int ? And mostly : WHY ?

Comment: @Fifi For variadic functions (like `printf`) all integer arguments smaller than `int` are promoted to `int`. It's called [default argument promotion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Default_argument_promotions). The same thing happens for `float`, it becomes promoted to `double` (which is why there's no difference between `"%f"` and `"%lf"` for `printf`).

Comment: @Some programmer dude in that case, why printf("%d",sizeof( ~a)); display 4 ?

Comment: @Fifi Because on jut about all common platforms `int` is 32 bits, which happens to be 4 bytes, which is what the `sizeof` operator correctly reports.

Comment: @Fifi because `sizeof` gives 4 (bytes) for an `int` on your system. Please mind that `sizeof` yields a value of type `size_t` and you should use `"%zu"` to `*printf()` it. Applying `~` to the `int` you use `sizeof` on is irrelevant.

Comment: @Fifi Oh and to be really correct, to print the result of `sizeof` you should use the `z` prefix, as in `"%zu"` (since `size_t`, which is the type of the result of `sizeof`, is unsigned). See e.g. [this `printf` (and family) reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf).

Comment: That's not the question. The question is why my unsigned char is transformed to int by the operator NOT (~) ?

Comment: @Fifi Becauls all types smaller `int` get promoted when an operation is performed on them: [Understanding interger conversation rules](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/INT02-C.+Understand+integer+conversion+rules)

Comment: @Fifi Please *read the links I provide*. The one about [integer promotion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Integer_promotions) includes the text "integer promotions are applied ... to the operand of the unary bitwise operator `~`"

Comment: @Swordfish this is the answer I expected. Could you post your comment as an answer, I will vote for and mark as best answer.

Comment: @Fifi So to get your desired result, you'd have to cast: `printf("%d\n", (int)((char unsigned)~a));`

Comment: @Swordfish Or use `"%hhu"`... :)

Comment: @Fifi - `sizeof( ~a))` is 4 for the same reason explained in the duplicate to your [previous quesion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53480031/why-the-operator-transforms-unsigned-char-to-int). You seem to have deleted that without actually trying to understand the dupe.

Comment: `printf("%hhu\n", ~a);` is technically  UB when `~a < 0`.  It passes an `int`  with a value not in the `unsigned` range where an `unsigned` is expected.

Answer (score 3):

> Why printf (“%d”, ~a); display -4 when a is equal to 3?
>   Why `~a` doesn't return an `unsigned char` since `a` is an `unsigned char`?

```
unsigned char a=3;
```

Because `~a` is an `int` -4, not an `unsigned char` 252, due to **integer promotions**.

---

Application of `~` causes an  *integer promotion* of `a` **before** the bit-wise complement is taken.

> If an `int` can represent all values of the original type ..., the value is converted to an `int`; otherwise, it is converted to an `unsigned int`. These are called the *integer promotions*.

`~3`, given the common 2's complement integer encoding, is -4.

---

On select platforms, `unsigned char, int, unsigned` are all the same bit-width.  On those exceptional platforms, `~a` may take on a value like  `FFFFFFFC` (`4294967292`) as it is promoted to `unsigned` instead.